# Finding the squares up to 10,000,000 in C

Tags: c, math

The sum of squares of the 3 consecutive numbers 11, 12 and 13 is 434 (that is 121 + 144 + 169 = 434). The number 434 reads the same from both ways and is called a palindrome. I need to find out the sum of the numbers less than `10^7` that can be expressed as the sum of consecutive squares and results in a
palindrome. If in 2 different sequences, a number repeats, then sum
them twice. That is if 11 occurs in 2 consecutive number sequences, sum it twice.

I need to write a program based on the above scenario.

What I understood is we have to find squares up to 10,000,000 and then all the numbers. How should I approach writing a program to do this in C?

Comment: Which part are you not understanding? How to find a square of a number? How to go through all of the numbers up to a certain number?  How to keep track of what numbers satisfy your criteria and what don't?

Comment: `I wonder how its possible to do with programming.` By being a programmer and showing us what you have done? :-)

Comment: How many numbers are in each sequence? 3? Or a variable amount?

Comment: Try `(*0)` and see if the undefined behavior happens to do what you want.

Comment: And I think there is an error in the text. It asks for the sum of numbers that are palindrome and are < 10^7 and are the sum of squares of three consecutive numbers, and then it adds the rule "If in 2 different sequences, a number repeats, then sum them twice." that makes it think that you should sum the 11, 12, 13 instead of the 434. (because clearly there can't be two equal sum of consecutive squares!)

Comment: Sounds like you'll need some kind of loop to iterate or you can do it recursively starting with 10000000.  Which will look better but will be harder to debug.  You'll probably have to watch you data types...  That's pretty much how I'd approach the problem.

Comment: I've once seen (and done) a puzzle like this, that required the hex-representation to be a palindrome, too.

Comment: Let's say this: it's more complex to check for palindromicity (is it a word?) than everything else :-)

Comment: I would suggest first writing a function that checks for palindromicity (it should be a word). Once you've done that, putting the whole thing together shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: I remember in my high school C++ class we had to write a function to check if a number was a palindrome, but we couldn't convert it to a string.  It took me forever to do, but I finally got it working.  The next day, no one else in the class had even tried so the teacher cancelled the whole thing.  Most useless code I've ever written.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a for loop which increments a variable? Using this variable you can generate 3 consecutive numbers.. then sum up the squared numbers.. if it's above your max number you stop the loop. if it's below you check whether it's a palindrom?

Answer (score 0):

Using brute force way is one such possible way.

Iterate a variable `i` from `1 to 10^7 - 2` so that you are going to take sum of squares of first three value of variable (including i) and find whether its palindrome or not.

ie. when `i=5`, in a `for` loop
you need to find whether i^2 + (i+1)^2 + (i+2)^2 is palindrome or not.

I am not sure but you rather take `long long` as you need to calculate squares.